# Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (computation): The type parameter is not nullable: null

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

Trying to run the following Flutter code in android Studio

[image]

Link to code on github
https://github.com/cyeh1234/bloc_bug.git

Got the following error:

[image]

https://www.mitrais.com/news-updates/getting-started-with-flutter-bloc-pattern/

Correct output

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Remove `<int>` will fix this issue.

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to specify type annotations use:

```
await Future<dynamic>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
```